# Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password while reading from Active directory

Tags: active-directory, authentication

I have wrapper web services to read from Active Directory. It works fine on DEV; but on Staging / QA, I am getting this error

Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

I am able telnet to the Active directory server on 389 (LDAP port) from both DEV & Staging boxes. I tried with different user accounts who has even read only access to active directory; all worked fine on DEV but not on Staging / QA. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

You might check the permissions of the account that runs the web service, usually on the Staging/QA the security requirements are higher.

**UPDATE** http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t619647-impersonating-and-windows-authentication.html

Comment: Please elaborate...that web site is enabled for Windows auth.

Comment: In the web service try the AD request while impersonating an account that has read access on AD.

Comment: Thanks. I tried without passing credentials (just ldapPath to DirectoryEntry instance); it worked fine. But, if I supply credentials, it is failing even for Read Only user (all developers has read-only access).  The only difference, I see between DEV & Staging is Dev is XP (5.1), Stg is 2003 (IIS 6).

Comment: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t619647-impersonating-and-windows-authentication.html

Comment: Its solved; I tried with Domain\Username (instead of username) and didn't change anything else. I did try with changing the app pool to run with domain user - didn't work. the link is meaningful and related to issue.. thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

That could be a lot of things, from improperly escaping the password (it probably has characters that are not in "normal" strings in whatever language you're using) to not including the AD DOMAIN name in the username (DOMAIN\username)

Comment: The kanguage is C#. The user & passwords ae encrypted strins stroed in config file. These are working fine in DEV,